# iPhone/iPad and iTunesArtwork

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes

I would like to include the file iTunesArtwork in my app bundle but I have an iPad and iPhone version of the app. The iPad version's icon has the letters HD over it. How should I proceed to include both versions on the project and tell Xcode to include one image or the other, so the correct image is copied to each bundle.

Thanks.

Comment: just a typo, but perhaps I am seeing something in my crystal ball...

Comment: haha, ok. answering question now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK. First of all, you should have 4 different files:

- Icon.png (57x57)
- Icon@2x.png (114x114)
- Icon-72.png (72x72)
- iTunesArtwork (512x512)

If your app is universal, the first three should be included in the app bundle, and everything will take care of itself as long as your Info.plist is created properly. If the app isn't universal, there's still no harm in including all three in the bundle.

In either case, you don't need to include iTunesArtwork in your app bundle if you're submitting to the App Store. You submit your 512x512 icon along with your app, and it will automatically be included in your bundle.

For Ad Hoc builds, including iTunesArtwork is entirely optional. If you want to include different iTunesArtwork files for two different targets, you can place the two files in different folders and include one in the first target, and the other one in the second.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, I thought the iTunesArtwork icon would be used for regular apps, not just adHoc. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this blog will help you getting more details about current grapichs required for iOS app submission.

[Icon Required for iOS Apps](http://knowledgetransferinobjectivec.blogspot.in/2012/05/itunesartwork-in-ios-apps.html)

thanks,

Naveen Shan