# Which official document describes the icons and iTunesArtwork that has to be included in an app bundle?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I've got the iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf, but a search for "Icon-Small" or "iTunesArtwork" returns no match.

There must be a different document which goes into detail what icons are needed, and specifically how the iTunesArtwork has to be created. Which one is it? I remember there was one which talked about iTunesArtwork and explicitely mentioning not to add an extension as well as not to add alpha, but that's almost 2 years ago.

Edit: Found it in the iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf on page 11. It's in a blurry image, so search didn't work because of that. Anyways, I also remember there was a more detailed discussion about this somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) and [the "App Icons on iPad and iPhone" Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) too.

There is also [this Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH19-SW14) that talks about the subject.

*Note: Got all this using a simple Google Search anyway*

Answer (score 1):

The "Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines" section of the iOS Human Interface Guidelines has detailed information about the various icons you need to create for your app: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Also, you don't need to include iTunesArtwork in your app bundle. See my answer to this question: [iPhone/iPad and iTunesArtwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335551/iphone-ipad-and-itunesartwork/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/app_store_guide.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_2) you can find the guide lines for preparing an app to be submit to app store